# How to not return a cell contitionally

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

In my `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` method, is it possible to not fill my table view with certain cells?

Right now my method looks something like this:

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    ResultsCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.title.text = [[resultsForCell objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"title"];
return cell;
```

but I want to make it so if objectforkey@"title" is equal to something have it not show on the tableview or not return that cell. I dont know the best way to accomplish this.

Comment: Why don't you filter the array first and then use it as the data source ?

Comment: You can presumably use the delegate's `heightForRowAtIndexPath` to set row height to zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to "filter" your table view you need to filter your source data. In this case you need to remove those values from resultsForCell.

If you want to hide a label on those cells you can just set the label's hidden to true.

Comment: You could also `return 0;` in `heightForRowAtIndexPath:`. It's lazy, but if there's not too much data the performance hit is minor.

Answer (score 0):

Define your indexPath values where you want to not to show anything. Then use those defined values in the above method in if block. For example:

If you select indexPathArray(1,3,5,6) as predefined array where rows must not be shown,

```
if(![indexPathArray containsObject:indexPath]){
//your code for Showing cells title.
}
```